# Combine scalar array references in perl

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I have a datastructure like:

```
$hashRef->{"key1"}->{"key2"} = ['1','2','3']
```

This `$hashRef` gets new values  every iteration of the for loop. I am trying to append all of these to produce an output like so:

```
$hashRef->{"key1"}->{"key2"} = ['loop1.out1','loop1.out2','loop1.out3','loop2.out1','loop2.out2','loop2.out3',...]
```

loop1.ou1 is symbolic for the first output from loop 1 and not intended to be printed.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know why, but the best answer according to me, was deleted. Here's a copy of the answer:


my $result = ['1','2','3'];

push @{ $hashRef->{key1}{key2} }, @$result;

Answer (score 0):

You may use `push` to append new values to the array:

```
push( @{$hashRef->{"key1"}->{"key2"}}, 'loop1.out1','loop1.out2','loop1.out3');
$aData = [ 'loop2.out1','loop2.out2','loop2.out3' ];
push( @{$hashRef->{"key1"}->{"key2"}}, @$aData);
print join(",",@{$hashRef->{"key1"}->{"key2"}} ),"\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you want:

```
map {
      push(@{$hashRef->{"key1"}->{"key2"}}, "loop$count.out".$_);      
    } @{$arr2};
```

$count is the loop number.
@{$arr1} is the incoming array.

Thanks,

Anoop

Comment: I don't actually need "loop1.ou1" etc to be printed, I just used the n to show the order I wanted the prints in...